# ASP.NET (C#) crystal reports export fails with "Method not found.."

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, report

as I said in title I have issue when I try to export crystal report to PDF, or anything like that, also when I try to print it I am having same issue, before anything I will post you screenshot to explain it more detailed:

[image]

I loaded report with my data from database and everything looks fine, reports is opened I can see my data, but when I try to export it to pdf or to print it I am seeing that Error, I've been trying for few hours to solve it, but unfortunately I couldn't make it working..

I have to mention, that I did next thing before this:
[image]

I set EnableDatabaseLogonPromt to False because before I did that, everytime I tried to do print or export I received this popup (so should I leave it setted to false to avoid this popup?)

[image]

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var x = Server.MapPath("~");

            int playerId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["playerID"]);
            PlayersDataSet players= new PlayersDataSet ();
            PlayersDataSet.PlayersTableDataTable playersDT = new PlayersDataSet.PlayersTableDataTable ();
            var player= Players.Data.Services.DAPlayers.GetByPlayerId(playerId);
            string clubname= Players.Data.Services.DAPlayers.GetClubNameByClubID(Convert.ToInt32(player.ClubID));
            playersDT.AddPlayersTableRow(player.FirstName, player.LastName, player.IDNUMBER, clubname, player.Photo, player.IDSerialNumber.ToString());

            players.Tables["PlayersTable"].Merge(playersDT);

            rpt_Players RPT = new rpt_Players ();
            RPT.SetDataSource(players);
            CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = RPT;

          }
```

Any kind of help would be great!
Thank you guys,
Cheers

Comment: Hi, do you use a database , login / password or a dataset ? If you let the popup and write the connection's informations, did the report work fine and can be exported ?

Comment: No it does not, it does not even let me choose database, that field is locked, and whatever I enter in Login etc it does not work..

Comment: But did you use a dataSet or you use directly your database in the report ?

Comment: I am using dataset to fill my datatable which is later source to my rpt file

Comment: Okay , Did you cache your CR object ? ( and retrieve it in the page_init ? )

Comment: I think that I did not, later I will edit my post and post my code there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122496/discussion-between-furtiro-and-roxypro).

Comment: anyone? stil having trouble with this

Comment: I am facing same identical issue, really don't know what might be useful, because code  is absolutely allright, something is wrong with crystal reports/export.

Answer (score 1):

Its stupid to answer my own questions but after hours and hours of searching and trying many different things, I've found that this is a solution: remove this condition : if(!ispostback){} and everything will be fine with exporting etc.. :)